# Orders are cancelling after successful payment is logged

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway

I have a client's large online retail site which we have been managing for about a year. Over the past two months things have become quite weird.

Customers appear to be placing orders through the site and are redirected to PayU Payment gateway. Now when they return to the site, the payment is captured, but what happens is a few seconds later, the order is cancelled (even though payment has been made).

Comment: Can you provide more information about your issue? You did research?

Comment: I have looked everywhere, it's almost as if no one else has had the same issue. One of my thoughts is that maybe when the payment gateway sends the user back, it is sending a second message saying that a timeout has occurred.